# HTML-Form / incomplete POST-Request

Tags: html, forms, post

(It sounds so incredible - but [here's](http://mbaas.redirectme.net/entersecret) my sample for validation...)

I have a form with three input-controls and when I submit it, only the checkbox is included in the POST-Data (taken from Chrome's Inspect / "Network"-tab):

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryTpyTtgjdgNzBqZuV
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mail"

checked
------WebKitFormBoundaryTpyTtgjdgNzBqZuV--
```

The form itself unfortunately is not minimalistic at all - it is embedded in various other controls and contains a table which holds the The HTML, however, validates - I checked that.)
The code of the relevant controls (all within the `table` inside of the `form`) is:

- `<input value="" type="text" id="rec">`
- `<input type="checkbox" value="mail" id="mail" name="mail" onclick="bs(this)">`
- `<textarea value="" rows="10" cols="80" id="txt"></textarea>`

I've spend hours with his now - maybe I just looked at too much code to see the simple explanation?

**P.S:** yes, I confess - layout / design is far from optimal, but my main concern was getting the request in... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you only gave the checkbox a 'name' (name="mail"). You'll need to give the others a name as well. The 'name' is what is used in PHP to access an input's value.

```
<input value="" type="text" id="rec" name="rec">
<input type="checkbox" value="mail" id="mail" name="mail" onclick="bs(this)">
<textarea value="" rows="10" cols="80" id="txt" name="txt"></textarea>
```

Comment: Aaaaargh - it had to be somewhere between my ears! ;-) I totally ignored that - thanks! :((

Answer (score 2):

When you create an HTML form, is not the id of the element, will be send in the request , it's the name:

for to get all your input elements you can add a name in your other inputs like that:

```
<form method="post" action=""> <!-- method == 'post' or 'get' -->
    <input value="" type="text" id="rec" name="rec" >
    <input type="checkbox" value="mail" id="mail" name="mail" onclick="bs(this)">
    <textarea value="" rows="10" cols="80" id="txt" name="txt"></textarea>
</form>
```

and get it (with php) for 'post' method:

```
$myRec = $_POST['rec']; // get the element with the name 'rec'
$myMail = $_POST['mail']; // get the element with the name 'mail'
$mytxt = $_POST['txt']; // get the element with the name 'txt'
```

and get it (with php) for 'get' method:

```
$myRec = $_GET['rec']; // get the element with the name 'rec'
$myMail = $_GET['mail']; // get the element with the name 'mail'
$mytxt = $_GET['txt']; // get the element with the name 'txt'
```

That will explain [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-form-name) on the official W3.org.

Comment: Thanks Doc - that explains everything! (I accepted executor's answer because he was a bit quicker and so I was down in tears already when your reply came....;-))

Comment: Not a big deal :p! The essential is you solved your problem! w3.org is the official organisation from the HTML. the documentation is very helpful!!